# OSX iCloud share files between apps

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, icloud

Is it possible to share files between different applications though iCloud? For example may I export epub book from my app to make it appear in iBooks or export a document to Pages from my application? And is there any way to get this files or pictures from photo stream in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to write files to another's application sandbox, precisely because the Sandbox won't let you write outside your app's container. What you can do is invoke a save panel to let the user export the file as an ebook wherever he wants. He can then open the file in Pages and move it to the cloud there.

And no, there is no API to access your Photo Stream.